# Coverage command with Vitest won't return the coverage report. Why?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vitest

Any kind soul could help me to "How to use the command-line coverage in my Vitest and Typescript project"???? It simply won't return me the coverage report.

It only return me how many tests have passed and the ones that failed.

I've install the "@vitest/-coverage-v8" and the command i'm running in the terminal is "npx vitest run --coverage".

The funny thing is that appears in my terminal this: "Coverage enabled with v8". But it runs one time and then stop.

What i'm missing???

Answer (score 0):

It will only show the report, when all of your tests are passed.